# mvn clean package собирает jar без зависимостей (библиотек)

Tags: spring, maven, jar

использую Intellij Idea

mvn clean package собирает jar в котором напрочь отсутствуют библиотеки (зависимости) указанные pom файле. jar-ник выходит весом пол мегабайта.

при этом jar артефакт (Build Artifact..) собирается полноценно и запускается. здесь вес jar-ника выходит 47 мегабайт.

проекты собираю не первый раз.

уже весь моск себе сломал. перелопатил Project structure. понимаю, что где то что то не так. но не могу понять где.

помогите, пожалуйста в какую сторону копать,

ниже содержимое pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.15</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.destiny</groupId>
    <artifactId>startup</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>Startup/name>
    <description>your start will be fine</description>


    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <start-class>com.destiny.startup.StartupApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <!-- исключаем стандартное логгирование спринга, из-за конфликта с log4j2 -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--        сохраняет сессии ремемберми в БД,-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

лог сборки:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.destiny:startup >-------------------------
[INFO] Building Startup 0.0.1
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] Parameter 'parameters' is unknown for plugin 'maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile)'
[WARNING] Parameter 'parameters' is unknown for plugin 'maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile)'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ startup ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 61 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ startup ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 60 source files to D:\IdeaProjects\SpringStartup\target\classes
[INFO] /D:/IdeaProjects/SpringStartup/src/main/java/com/destiny/startup/config/SecurityConfig.java: D:\IdeaProjects\SpringStartup\src\main\java\com\destiny\startup\config\SecurityConfig.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[INFO] /D:/IdeaProjects/SpringStartup/src/main/java/com/destiny/startup/config/SecurityConfig.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ startup---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\IdeaProjects\SpringStartup\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ startup ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- surefire:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ startup ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jar:3.2.2:jar (default-jar) @ startup ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\IdeaProjects\SpringStartup\target\startup-0.0.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.856 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-20T19:34:03+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 4 plugin(s)
[WARNING] 
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.2
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]
[WARNING] 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

с этим заработало. собралось. запустилось.

пока до конца не могу понять как, и по чему без этого плагина нормально работало прежде,

UPD.:
разобрался.

при использовании плагина `maven-compiler-plugin` (пакета `org.apache.maven.plugins`) необходимы дополнительные настройки (указать `<start-class/>`, указать ресурсы, инклуд библиотек в жарник (`maven-shade-plugin`) и прочее).

но если у вас проект на фреймворке SpringBoot то альтернативой при сборке жарника будет плагин `spring-boot-maven-plugin` пакета `org.springframework.boot`. в таком случае все эти дополнительные настройки в pom-файле указывать нет необходимости, SpringBoot-плагин возьмет это на себя.

в моём случае я как раз таки по ошибке использовал

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
```

вместо

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

который благополучно использовал раньше.